# Find files shared outside organization - Google Drive

Tags: google-workspace, drive

I'm using Google Workspace.

I just received an email alert from Google saying that "74% of potentially sensitive files have been shared outside your organization".

I'm trying to answer two questions :

- Which files ?
- Which user did this ?

I tried the app "whohasaccess". However, I didn't see anything abnormal.

What can I do / use to understand what exactly happened ?